# Looking up removed friend requests

Tags: facebook-friend-request

A friend sent a request to me, then they removed that request before I even looked into who they are. Is there a way to look them up if you don't remember their name?

Answer (score 4):

No, if someone has cancelled a friend request there is no list available to see them.